# How to change format of date in Sybase SQL?

Tags: sql, date, format, sybase

Hellow, I have column "MyDate" in table "MyTable" in Sybase SQL. Column "MyDate" has type data and format of data is for example Jan 3, 1902. My question is how can I change format of present date from `Jan 3, 1902` to for example `1902/01/03`?
Could you write my whole code which can do it, not briefly answer please :) Thank you.

Comment: which Sybase product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version? what is the actual datatype of the `MyDate` column? what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> DATEFORMAT ( datetime-expression, string-expression )

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyDate= DATEFORMAT(MyDate,'NEW_DATE_FORMAT');
```

> [How to Change Date Format in Sybase](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1520/html/iqrefbb/Dateformat.htm)

Or you can use

> CONVERT ( data-type, expression [ , format-style ] )

```
select CONVERT( CHAR( 20 ), MyDate, 104 ) from MyTable
```

[CONVERT In Sybase](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1520/html/iqrefbb/Convert.htm)

Comment: I mean, how to write a query that will return the MyData date in YYYY/MM/DD format

Comment: Then you can use: Select DATEFORMAT (MyDate, 'NEW_DATE_FORMAT')  from MyTable;.

Comment: so if i want to have for example 1903/03/01 I need to write Select DATEFORMAT (MyDate, 'YYYY/MM/DD') from MyTable ??

Comment: Yes right and you can also use Convert. I have included that in my answer.